# Kafka offsets are not always committed

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-beam

I want to send a message to Kafka and read it without auto-commit.

I send messages like that:

```
private Producer<Void, String> createProducer(String kafkaBootstrapServers) {
   return new KafkaProducer<>(
       ImmutableMap.of(
           ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaBootstrapServers,
           ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, UUID.randomUUID().toString()
       ),
       new VoidSerializer(),
       new StringSerializer());
}


private void sendToKafka(int partition, String... messages) {
    try (Producer<Void, String> producer = createProducer(kafkaContainerBootstrapServers)) {
        Arrays.stream(messages).forEach(
            message -> producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(KAFKA_TOPIC, partition, null, message)));
    }
}
```

I read it from Kafka with Apache Beam:

```
    KafkaIO.<Void, String>read()
            .withBootstrapServers(options.getKafkaBootstrapServers())
            .withProcessingTime()
            .withKeyDeserializer(VoidDeserializer.class)
            .withValueDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
            .updateConsumerProperties(new ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Object>()
                .put(ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false)
                .put(AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, options.getKafkaConsumerOffsetReset())
                .put(GROUP_ID_CONFIG, options.getKafkaConsumerGroup())
                .build())
            .withConsumerFactoryFn(new ConsumerFactoryFn())
            .commitOffsetsInFinalize()
            .withReadCommitted();
```

But offsets are not always committed.

I use this command to see offsets:

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --formatter "kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager\$OffsetsMessageFormatter" --bootstrap-server localhost:43881 --topic __consumer_offsets --from-beginning
```

I have three partitions.

First, I need to send more than 10 messages for a partition to see offset for this partition (doesn't know why). When I had one partition and sent 11 messages, all worked well.

```
[group,test,0]::OffsetAndMetadata(offset=10, leaderEpoch=Optional.empty, metadata=, commitTimestamp=1553866358077, expireTimestamp=Some(1554471158077))
```

Second, I don't sometimes have offsets for each partition even when sending 11 messages for each one (after changing from 1 to 3 partitions).

Comment: Your bean might be committing offsets for you. https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kafka/KafkaIO.Read.html#commitOffsetsInFinalize--

Comment: If you use core Kafka core API directly then you will get more assurance of what's going on.

Comment: I know but it should always commit them not sometimes.

Comment: Have you checked out the `auto.commit.interval.ms` & `commit.interval.ms` config properties? Check the docs here: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/

Comment: auto.commit.interval.ms is only for enable.auto.commit=true

Comment: And commit.interval.ms is for KafkaStreams. I need the same with Apache Beam.